# how to get access token from vscode forge extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, autodesk-forge

@ 12:29 of Petr's YouTube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8It7_3Mct6c, I noticed that access token can be retrieved directly, how to do it? many Autodesk Forge tools seem lack of this feature or not documented i.e. https://oss-manager.autodesk.io/, https://da-manager.autodesk.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just an extension command provided by Petr's Forge vscode extension. In this context, it is called Forge Oauth API to generate an access token.

See:

https://github.com/petrbroz/vscode-forge-tools/blob/2a406c4fc7d0135eeef2e451dbfedc12534cd321/src/commands/authentication.ts#L57

Steps to get access token with this extension command:

1. Go to the Forge vscode extension by clicking the Forge icon at the left sidebar.
2. Press F1 to open the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette).
3. Type Forge Auth
4. Press enter
5. Enter OAuth scopes
6. Press enter

Comment: F1, that's it, thanks Eason! similar tips (to get access token) for other 2 popular tools i.e. https://oss-manager.autodesk.io and https://da-manager.autodesk.io? well, not critical but always good to get all needed info when using one specific tool

Comment: they are different tools, but commonly, their access tokens are from an ajax call from their backend, https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-buckets-tools/blob/master/www/js/scripts.js#L307, https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-buckets-tools/blob/master/server/server.js#L53, https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-designautomation-tools/blob/da2aac327dcb35793e65c8673c0171da209be70a/www/js/scripts.js#L311, https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-designautomation-tools/blob/master/server/server.js#L53

Comment: right, I can use curl or postman to get result quickly, thanks Eason